# how to make my content area to the right of my menu?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hello im trying to put my content area to the right of my vertical nav bar using bootstrap 4. in my current code the content area is under the menu. any suggestions on how to fix it so its next to the menu on the right side.
Thank you

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-3">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="collapsibleNavbar" style>
 <ul class="navbar.flex-column">
 <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Index</a>
 </li>

 </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-9">

 <p>Main Content area</p>

 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try using bootstrap grids for getting the required layout.

Comment: @Srikanth that's why I'm trying to use nut it's not working any suggestions on how I can properly do it. I know that the grid is 12 so I'm trying to do my menu 3 and then my content area 9 but they keep on staying under each other

Comment: Enclose the whole thing in a div with class="row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `col-9` div and place it after the `col-3` div ends. Add `d-flex flex-row` classes with `container-fluid` class.

Comment: Zahid its still the same they are under each other

Comment: Please remove the `container-fluid` div before the `col-9` div. There should be only one `container-fluid` div.

Comment: Zahid bro I removed the container-fluid before the col-9 div and I pasted the col-9 where you told me but it's still the same. They are still under each other I'm trying to make the content to the write of the menu

Comment: Zahid if you can run my code you'll understand whats happening

Comment: i Fixed it thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think you do the same. One thing I missed that is there is `.` before `flex-column` class that you need to remove.